# how can i store my python gui program as desktop app?

Tags: python, selenium, user-interface, desktop-application

**So i wrote a Python program in which i included a gui, how can i turn the program to a desktop app, which i can open it without opening the text editor and executing it.The code is the following(when i enter the name of a video in the gui, it looks it up on youtube and plays the first video in the result page )**

````
```from selenium import webdriver
   from tkinter import * 
   root=Tk()
   root.title('Youtube Video Player')
   text=Label(root,text="In order to save time and avoid procrastination.\nEnter the name of the 
   video you have in mind,and by the power of the gods it will play")
   text.pack()
   input=Entry()
   input.pack()
   def vidplayer():
           a=str(input.get())
           browser=webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Downloads\\chromedriver')
           browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='+a)
           video=browser.find_element_by_id('video-title')
           video.click()
   button=Button(text="Play Video", command=vidplayer)
   button.pack()
   root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like http://www.pyinstaller.org/ which are to pack your python code into executable that is native to your particular OS.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to "freeze" your code. There are plenty of distribution utilities out there. You can start with the official documentation.

[Python Wiki - Distribution Utilities](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributionUtilities)

I've had a lot of success with both cxFreeze and PyInstaller.

Comment: i've tried pyinstaller, but the dist file that contains the .exe is empty

Comment: Are you receiving any errors or warnings on the command line? Can you run the script at the command line successfully?  I copy/pasted your code above into a script called test.py, then ran pyinstaller test.py and have a working exe and all supporting files in dist/test.

Comment: ERROR: failed building wheel for cx_freeze                                                                           even though ihave installed wheel earlier, it still doesn"t work. I think the cx_freeze version is not supported by python 3.7, maybe i have to downgrade my python version

Comment: As of August cx_Freeze v6 works with python 3.7.  If you don't have v6 try that, otherwise if you paste the full output of the error (it will be long) we might be able to see if there's a missing dependency or other issue.